# Redirect all my site links except (example.com)

Tags: javascript

I want to redirect all links except for a specific URL (`example.com`)

I used this JavaScript code:

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].href = "http://test.com/url=" + anchors[i].href
}

  </script>
```

Comment: I want to redirect all links except for a specific URL (site.com)

Comment: PLEASE stop altering your question from what it was originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a small change:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

  for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    if (!anchors[i].href.match(/site\.com/))
      anchors[i].href = "http://test.com/url=" + anchors[i].href
  }
}
```

Comment: You did not understand what I meant
I want to redirect external links except my (site.com)